# How to pull data that are in a specific pattern in MYSQL and PHP

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a MySQL table and on of the column that contains username in different patterns. I am wondering is there a way to pull the usernames that (first 3 positions are in letter and last 4 positions are in number)? So I want to pull ABE0005, LKD0125, GHD0011, etc... See below for username examples.

```
username column:
ABE0005
LKD0125
905593580
GHD0011
903649229
BAN_SS_USER
```

This is how I pull data for username that starts with 9.

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE term = '2022' AND user LIKE '9%'");
    
$b_202310_3 = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: And what about "ABElots_of_other_stuff0005"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `regexp` in a `where` clause to achieve this.

```
where username regexp '^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$'
```

`^` is the start of the string
`[A-Z]` is any uppercase alpha character
`{3}` is 3 characters of the preceding group/class
`[0-9]` is any single integer
`{4}` is 4 of previous group/class
`$` is the end of the string

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/LFFc4f/1 (Note this tool is using PCRE, MySQL uses POSIX (e.g. something like `\d` won't work in MySQL but would in this tool))

Per update query should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE term = '2022' AND user REGEXP '^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$'
```

Comment: Put the `W:` after the `^`. You can test things in the regex101 link.